# Decimal Field In Hive Only Returning Results When Encapsulating Value In Single Quotes

Tags: sql-server, hive, decimal, hiveql

I ingested a table from a SQLServer database into a Hive database. When I attempt to do a lookup on a value in Hive, I have to surround the value with single quotes in order to find it.

In SQLServer, the datatype for the column is numeric(21,0). The front-end tool we used to migrate the data (as well as provide reporting, etc.), Solix CDP, has mapped this value to a decimal(38,13) in Hive.

The following is a matrix of anonymized search values and results:

```
select * from [table] where num = 1;
|   |
select * from [table] where num = '1';
| 1 |
select * from [table] where num like 1;
|   |
select * from [table] where num like '1';
| 1 |
```

The Solix tool does not handle wrapping the value in single quotes in a report, so I need to figure out a way to return a result "traditionally" ie without single quotes.

What would be causing this issue?

Thanks.

Comment: What about `= 1.0` ?

Comment: What about `= cast(1 as decimal(21,0))` ?

Comment: Note that your Solix mapping is absurd, it should have used a Hive type of `decimal(21,0)`

Comment: Oh, I totally agree about the absurdity. It was set by the vendor. I'm going to try seeing if I can change that mapping to fix it.

As for your other two suggestions, neither of them produced any results, and neither did `cast(num as decimal(21,0)) =`. Appreciate the suggestions, though. I'll update my main post with the results of changing that mapping, if possible.

Comment: BTW, what kind of _physical_ data format are you using for that Hive table -- sthg with binary storage of numbers (Parquet, ORC) or just plain `TextFile` using text representation?

Comment: Thanks for the help, @SamsonScharfrichter. I've modified the mapping so it reads the source precision instead of hardcoding it to max (why the Vendor didn't do that I'll never know) but doesn't seem to have fixed the issue. I am using ORC for the physical format - Parquet was giving us issues with data ingestioninto Hive.

Comment: BTW did you read the Hive documentation about how to enter _literal_ integers stored as DECIMAL values e.g. `1BD`? https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+Types#LanguageManualTypes-DecimalLiteralsDecimalLiterals

Comment: Hmmm, that would probably be my issue then.

Unfortunately I don't really have a way to test it - I don't have access or permissions to change the data in the source SQLServer system, and when I try to manually insert a value like that I get an error in Beeline. I think my best option would be to solve it "correctly" and have the data owners redefine the fields (which are ID fields stored as numbers) as text.